# How to modify the DOM directly in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have two arrays `selectedFoobars` and `unselectedFoobars`. These are my data and they are rendered as lists next to each other using ReactJS.

When the user clicks on an element in one of the lists I want to remove the element from that list, and add it to the end of the other list. That part is pretty straight forward using React.

But, I want the clicked element to sweep across the screen from its old position to its new position in the other list. If the user clicks on and element in the middle of the `unselectedFoobars` that element should animate across the page to the bottom of the `selectedFoobars` list.

I don't just want the moved element to fade out it the first list and fade in in the second. That would have been easy though, by using the animation hooks provided the [animation addon](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) for React.

That is one – as far as I can tell – valid example of a problem where one needs to modify the DOM directly to achieve the desired result.

Using Backbone.js one could easily do the DOM manipulation manually. This is straight forward and pretty clean in Backbone-world albeit quite but a bit of work. In AngularJS I'd create a directive. It would be pretty unidiomatic Angular. But it would get the job done.

What is the cleanest way to handle this and similar cases where direct DOM manipulation is needed using ReactJS?

Comment: You need to write your own component for that. That doesn't come built-in with React.

Comment: But as far as I can tell React components only deal with the virtual DOM. To implement this one would have to touch the actual DOM.

Comment: Your virtual dom would work the same as a dom transformation. First you'd animate the element into position. Then you'd transfer that element to it's new parent. Making this seamless would be challenging, but I think that's true with any of the solutions.

Comment: As far as I can see it doesn't work the same as an actual DOM tranformation. How whould I modify – for instance – the position of an element? I can't do that directly.

Comment: Like a dom elements you modify it's style property with absolute positioning, I've done this with great results using ReboundJS to animate the position properties. Once the element is at rest in it's final position you could do the transfer to the new parent.

Comment: As in using [inline styles](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)? But what if I want to reuse the old element and add it to the new list?

Comment: I created this animation of List few days ago, it might be a good starting point for you. http://jsfiddle.net/0maphg47/1/

Comment: Thanks for the example! Reordering a list is another problem I've thought about. But how would you achieve that if you couldn't rely on all the list elements having the same height? Then you'd need to query the elements for their actual height. But how will you do that when working with the virtual DOM? I'm asking about the cases that can not be handled merely by using Reacts inline styles as in your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To manipulate a React component's "actual DOM" you can grab a reference of it using [`getDOMNode()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode).

However, referencing the "actual DOM" is not necessarily the only solution. For instance, instead of separating your `foobars` into selected/unselected arrays, you could pool them into a single array where each item specifies itself as being selected or not. For example:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    foobars: [ {text: 'item1', selected: false} ]
},

render: function(){
  return this.state.foobars.map(function(item){
    return <Foobar selected={item.selected}>{ item.text }</Foobar>;
  });
}
```

Then your `Foobar` component could set the `className` based on `this.props.selected`. You could then utilize the [animation addon](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) or some other CSS3 transition technique.

Comment: It appears that using `getDOMNode` is the best option.