# Is it good practice to set CSS variable in the React's render method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-variables

*I have created a post yestarday and deleted it by error*
I have to create a component with specific style. The problem is that the componentDidMount() method creates some king of flickering when rendering the component. It is the time that the CSS became set.

*I think my component is ressource's demanding so the `componentDidMount()` occurs with a little frame or two of lagging.  That why I am providing here just a snippet instead of a full demo, my little demo works well with zero specific flickering.*

I have then entering the value in the render's method. Like the following:

```
componentDidMount(){
   // the CSS rendering will lag by releasing a flickering :/
}

render(){

    // awesome, by setting my style in the render the good style is returned instantly.

    if (Math.round(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight +50) >= Math.round(document.body.scrollHeight)) {

            document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-transition', "")
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--is-page-bottom', "orange");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-transition', "all 0.3s ease-out")
         }
             else{
                //setIsPageBottom_CSSVariable("rgba(84, 80, 79,0.85)")
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-transition', "")
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--is-page-bottom', "purple");
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background-transition', "all 0.3s ease-out")
             }
```

Someone yesterday told me that I should use react React Hook to manage this case, or componentDidMount but componentDidMount fails in my case because of the flickering before installing the relevant background color.

I am new to React Hook so if I understand well I can make something like document.documentElement.style.setProperty in useEffect directly and it would be coherent with the design of React hook?

Meanwhile I find my solution is just good because [when reading the official React's documentation, it is noted that](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render):

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify
>   component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked,
>   and it does not directly interact with the browser.
>
> If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in
>   componentDidMount() or the other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping
>   render() pure makes components easier to think about.

Okay, if I can *think about* my component with a limpid manner so it is in no way a bad thing to do it isn't it? Just not the best practice I assume.
I have been advised to use an addeventlistener but here it is about instantly rendering my style on the first render component's loop. So addeventlistener is a solution for a different case that the one I am on.

In all case, which alternative would you recommend that avoid flickering when inserting my CSS setting in componentDidMount()? What is the link with the React hook?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can use useEffect

```
//componentDidMount replacement
useEffect(() => {
 //your code goes here
}, [])
```

Comment: Hope this link will help you better to understand this in detail
https://medium.com/@divyabiyani26/react-useeffect-a-hook-to-introduce-lifecycle-methods-in-functional-components-e7ec52897188

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) as it fires synchronously with the DOM changes. If normal useEffect retains the issue, then you should be able to use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not good practice - you would be better off changing the class name dynamically using react, dependent on the internal state of the component.

So you could use the useState hook, and have your component in a 'loading state' which would then apply a class.

Then you could add / remove class names and associated styles using react as well, rather than inserting them with JS.

Have a look at the classNames package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Your css would then be: `.additional-class {
background: red;
}`

or whatever you wanted.

Applying styles directly from React is somewhat missing the point of using react, to be honest. If you do want to do that, there are ways but should be limited, really: [How to modify the DOM directly in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621440/how-to-modify-the-dom-directly-in-reactjs)

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: thanks you for you recommendations JG3. When you are saying, _Applying styles directly from React is somewhat missing the point of using react_,  You mean from your point of view even using ref to change style is not the better way, and we would prioritize dynamic class on other mean to manage the appearing of the component?

Comment: Hi, no problem. Yes, as I understand it you don't want to directly manipulate the DOM with React wherever possible. To understand 'why did something on the page change' it could be as simple as component X received Y prop which added a class.

In your example, without knowing exactly one component will look at the window and apply styles based on a condition, it can become difficult to understand why something changed.

Refs can be used for those situations where you really need to access dom elements (like to find the height of a something).
Hope that helps.